# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>' (0x7f7f9fc3d0c0) to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I got an error in the parsing the data for URL Error is below..If any one knows the answer please ping me

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional'
>   (0x7f7f9fc3d0c0) to 'NSArray' (0x600000051598).

[image: MY Code]

**Error Message**:
[image: MY Error]

Comment: Don't use `NSArray`, use the native `Swift` counterpart, `Array<Type>`. Your `responseObject` is nil, hence the error. And in the future please include code as properly formatted text in your question and not as a screenshot.

Comment: but i got the values from the URl

Comment: And i did't have any idea to slove this problem.please give a solution

Comment: Any reason why you prefer AFNetworking to Alamofire (which is more Swifty and created by the "same team") ?

Comment: https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: whats is the solution for this

Comment: You don't have data in your response, so it is not possible to typecast data in your array..!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jut assuming that the response from the service is OK, you need to be testing it to see if it is nil or not before attempting to do anything with it. You should either use a guard or an if let e.g.

```
if let responseOject = responseObject
{
    // cast to swift array
}
else 
{
    // handle the error
}
```

Now you just need to figure out why your request failed. I would check the documentation for [AFHTTPRequestOperation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html) to see what diagnostic information it will give you. Also, it would be worth printing the URL out before you make the call so you can paste it directly into a browser.